# Cocos2d-Things appear bigger in simulator

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, screen

I've recently noticed that things accommodate differently on the simulator and a real device when using Cocos2d.To make sure I did the following:
1. I created a blank Cocos2d project. In the init method I created 7 sprites from Icon-72.png(which is found in the resources folder of the Cocos2d template) and added them to the screen.In the simulator only 6.5 sprites could accommodate side-by-side whereas in the iPod touch all seven sprites could accommodate easily and almost half of the screen width remained unused.
2.Then I created a project from Single View Application template. I added the same Icon-72.png  to the project. Then on the storyboard I added 6 image views and set their image property to Icon-72.png. This time I had exactly the same result with both simulator and the device.

I guess there should be some tweak as to how to fix this issue with Cocos2d because it's not Apple's fault. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: Which version of cocos2d is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPod Touch could have the retina display and the simulator wont have have it. If you need the same display as of the iPod Touch You can use the iPhone Simulator with the Retina Display and you would get the same screen. Another Option you can use is Copy and paste the Same file with -hd prefix ex:(Icon-72-hd.png) with 72x72 size and you can get the same result.

There is no problem with either the version of cocos2d or with the Apple for the issue you are facing.

I guess I do have poor explanation but you would understand my explanation.

Comment: You're asolutely right and I made my assumption sure after reading your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The iPod Touch will be a retina display. Cocos2d doesn't automatically double the size of images.

Comment: Could you please broaden your answer. I didn't quite get it.